# Getting the similarity grad between multiple vectors ?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have wrote a program to analyse the multiple audio files, the algorithm is long, but now I have  a result that I was expecting, the problem that is how to describ the similarity grad between the diffrent vectors that I've got :
[image]
[image]
[image]

I know that the cross correlation is a way to do that, but I can't conclude from the result of :

```
xcorr(x1,x2,'coeff')
```

anything I get a bunch of number that I can't interpret . so my question how can evaluate the similarity between the different curves, and please I'm asking for code too so I can understand, even if it one line.

thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) and look at the off-diagonal value. For example:

```
>> x1 = 1:12;
>> x2 = 1:12;
>> c = corrcoef(x1,x2);
>> c(1,2)
ans =
     1 %// equal vectors

>> x2(end) = 13;
>> c = corrcoef(x1,x2);
>> c(1,2)
ans =
    0.9977 %// slightly different

>> x2 = rand(1,12);
>> c = corrcoef(x1,x2);
>> c(1,2)
ans =
    0.0349 %// hardly any correlation
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer,just one question why should I look at c(2,1) ?

Comment: Because `c(1,1)` is similarity between `x1` and `x1`, so it's always `1`. You should look at `c(1,2)` or `c(2,1)` (they are the same, at least for real vectors) to measure similarity between both input arguments. `c(2,2)` is always `1` too